# How to create a calculated field from a user input and a value from a SQL database

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I am trying to add have a calculated field where a user enters in a number for the quantity of an order and displays the total cost of that product

I have a table for the list of products and there details from my sql database

```
if ($num_results1 > 0) {
     echo "<table><tr><th>Row Number</th><th>Name</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Weight</th><th>Price</th><th>Total</th></tr>";

for ($i=0; $i <$num_results1; $i++)
{

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
echo
    "<tr>".
    "<td class = 'row-number'>". $i ."</td>".
    "<td class = 'Product-Name'>". $row["Cheese"]."</td>".
    "<td class = 'Quantity'>" .'<input type="number" name="Box" id="text" />'. "</td>".
    "<td class = 'Weight'>" . $row["Size(in Kg)"] ."kg". "</td>".
    "<td class = 'Cost'>" ."€ ". $row["SellingPrice(Euro)"]. "</td>".
    "<td class = 'total'>".'calculate('.$row["SellingPrice(Euro)"].')'."</input></td>".
    "</tr>";
```

`calculate()` is a Javascript function I am writing to get the cost of the product by the amount the customer wants to order

```
<script>
    function getQuantity(i)
    {
    //reference to the form
    var theForm =document.forms["customerOrder"];
    //referenece to the element
    var quantity = theForm.elements["Box"];
        var howmany=0;
    if(quantity[i].value!="")
    {
        howmany=parseInt(quantity[i].value);
    }
    return howmany;
    } 

    function calculate(k)
    {
    var calc= '.$row["SellingPrice(Euro)"].' * getQuantity(k);
    return calc;
    }
</script>
```

getQuantity() trys to pull the value the customer entered into the webpage.

I have tried calling the scripts with echo in the php code, my problem I think is trying  to get the reference for Quantity

so in conclusion I am looking to create a function to calculate total cost and display that in my last column and it needs to be dynamic to fit the my sql database as the number of products for sale changes, Thanks

Comment: What's that `</input>` in the last <td> ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot proceed like you do. If you have multiple rows, you cannot pass PHP multiple values in ONE single javascript function. You can add some ID to your HTML tags to be able to retrieve the fields. Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ceqLpbL2/) to show you an example.

So in your case you can do this :

```
if ($num_results1 > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>Row Number</th><th>Name</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Weight</th><th>Price</th><th>Total</th></tr>";

    for ($i=0; $i <$num_results1; $i++)
    {

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
        echo
        "<tr>".
        "<td class = 'row-number'>". $i ."</td>".
        "<td class = 'Product-Name'>". $row["Cheese"]."</td>".
        "<td class = 'Quantity'>" .'<input type="number" id="qty-'.$i.'" onchange="calculate('.$i.')" />'. "</td>".
        "<td class = 'Weight'>" . $row["Size(in Kg)"] ."kg". "</td>".
        "<td class = 'Cost'>€ <span id='qty-".$i."'>". $row["SellingPrice(Euro)"]. "</span></td>".
        "<td class = 'total' id='total-".$i."'></td>".
        "</tr>";
    }
}
```

And the javascript :

```
<script>
    function calculate(lineNumber) {
            var quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById('qty-' + lineNumber).value);
            var cost = parseInt(document.getElementById('cost-' + lineNumber).innerHTML);

            document.getElementById('total-' + lineNumber).innerHTML = cost * quantity;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help with this but I can't seem to get it to work, I have tried echo out the javascript in the php code and also tried in the html, looked at the jsfiddle link, very helpful but can't seem to get it to work

Comment: Change the value in the input in jsfiddle